# Let $I_i$ be ideals, why $I_1\cdot ...\cdot I_{s-1}+I_s=\left(I_1\cap ...\cap I_{s-1}\right)\cap I_s$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, chinese-remainder-theorem

We want to prove the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and for s>2 we got to the point that:

$$R/\left(\left(I_1\cap ...\cap I_{s-1}\right)\cap I_s\right)=R/\left(\left(I_1\cdot ...\cdot I_{s-1}\right)+I_s\right)\:\simeq \:R/\left(I_1\cdot ...\cdot I_{s-1}\right)\:\times \:R/I_s\:=\:\left(R/I_1\:\times \:...\:\times \:R/I_{s-1}\right)\times R/I_s$$

I understand that the last equal sign comes from our induction assumption (as we proved it for s=2 already).

What I don't get is that what we wanted to also show (besides the isomorphism) is that $$I_1\cdot ...\cdot I_s=I_1\cap ...\cap I_s$$ but we get

$$\left(I_1\cdot ...\cdot I_{s-1}\right)+I_s=I_1\cap ...\cap I_s$$

apparently

So where's the mistake here? We already showed that

$$\left(I_1\cdot ...\cdot I_{s-1}\right)+I_s = R$$

Because $$1\in \left(I_1+I_s\right)...\left(I_{s-1}+I_s\right)\subset \left(I_1\cdot ...\cdot I_{s-1}\right)+I_s$$

Comment: It would probably help if there's a link to the argument you are following. The statement is doesn't make sense as written... what is probably intended is $R/((I_1\cap\ldots \cap I_{n-1})\cap I_n)= R/((I_1\cdot\ldots\cdot I_{n-1})\cap I_n)\simeq\ldots$

Comment: That would make more sense tbh

Comment: But then it should be $\left(I_1\cdot ...\cdot I_{s-1}\right)\cap I_s = R$, and not $\left(I_1\cdot ...\cdot I_{s-1}\right)+I_s = R$ how it should actually be

Comment: No, $(I_1\cdot\ldots\cdot I_{s-1}) + I_s = R$ is correct. This means that $(I_1\cdot\ldots\cdot I_{s-1}) $ and $I_s$ are coprime, so you can apply the $n=2$ case to get that $ R/ ((I_1\cdot\ldots \cdot I_{s-1})\cap I_s ) \simeq R/(I_1\cdot\ldots\cdot I_{s-1}) \times R/I_s.$